# Item to be bucketed according to a date field when created

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, bucket

I have created a content item at /sitecore/Home/FootballFever/**Articles** and have given insert option so that we can add only items of templates "**Article**".As of now,these article items are bucketable according to a field created date.

Now, i have insert option "Add Article" and "Insert from Template" buttons in the Home ribbon "Insert" block. When i create an item through "Insert from Template", the item automatically gets added in respective bucket with path as created date. for example if the item has created date is "7/21/2014" then path will be "/Articles/2014/7/21/ ".

But when i click on "Add Article", the item gets added in /Articles and i have to Sync everytime to get it to correct path.
How can I have the same behavior as that of "Insert from Template" but with path having **Release date** which is a field of template "Article"?

Comment: How have you specified that your Articles should be structured in your bucket according to the `Release Date`? Have you created a custom rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure that **Article** template has **Bucketable** field checked in its **Standard values** (for Article template).

If not, when you add a new item into buckets folder, newly added item itself is not bucketable, unlike the rest already existing items from the same bucket folder.

I have just made a proof of concept on my sandbox environment and can confirm that in case you add a new item with Bucketable checked by Standard values - it comes into a bucket straight away and you **do not need to perform Sync**.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** I have written a blog post specially to cover your question,with comprehensive description.

http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/understanding-buckets-adding-new-items-to-buckets-correctly

Comment: Yes the Article template has Bucketable ticked. What i have in mind is to create a custom rule for this release-date behavior but i aint sure How to..

Comment: Saying Article template are you meaning **Standard values** underneath article template? I highly suspect you are having something misconfigured, because message I described above does the job exactly like you want it to be - I have tested new item and is located within bucked with the date of creation

Comment: I have written a blog post for that particular issue, please have the link above

Comment: I went through your blog which is nice. Date of Creation has no issues...that is the default rule added in Bucket Settings. I want the same behavior but  with custom field "Release Date".
I was looking for some similar configuration in sitecore which does not involve any custom coding. But it seems i will have to create custom rules as suggested by Christain.

Comment: Also. I have an issue with Sitecore 7.0. I cannot see the "Edit Rule" field in Item Bucket Settings. But for Sitecore 8, it is present...!!

Answer (score 1):

By default, items will be structured in bucket folders, five levels deep based on the date and time the item was created. There are a couple of other built in rules you can use like using part of the Guid or part of the name. The thing to note here is that these are all things that are available on item creation. If you want to structure your articles based on a custom 'Release Date' then you will need to write a custom rule and you will also have to implement an `OnItemSaved` event handler. [Here is a article](http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/07/configuring-sitecore-item-buckets-with_19.html) on how to write the custom rule.

Generally you don't have to worry about how the items are structured in your bucket. Editors should be using the search tab to find the items they need.

Having said that, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24751818/202) discusses how to structure your bucket items based on a custom field. Some things to note here is that this is generally a global change. There are ways around it that enables you to have different strategies for different buckets but you'll then have to do additional work to override the `LinkProvider` and potentially other things.

Comment: So you mean to say that by adding a custom rule and necessary code, and then implement the OnItemSaved event handler, new items (on creation- as in case of "Insert from Template") will automatically be bucketted by "Release Date". Would give it a try but I am unable to find the "Edit rule" section in Item Bucket Settings and "Rules"(/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Bucketing) section in system/Settings. If you have anything on that, would help a lot. Thank you..

Comment: You need to navigate to the _Rules for Resolving the Bucket Folder Path_ field of `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings` to edit the rule. See this blog post for an example: http://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/4/how-to-create-custom-item-bucket-rules-in-sitecore-cms

Comment: Also, can we have multiple rules (default or custom) with different templates ?